# Is there a mobile and wear app shared storage?

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm currently developping a react native mobile app and an android wear app. I need the watch to get access to some data available in the mobile app (a token), but I want to be able to do it even when the mobile app isn't running. Is there a storage that can be accessed by both ?

Comment: How about Firebase Storage ? maybe even Firestore

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know automatically shared storage between mobile and wear app does not exist.
The solution is to use some cloud storage, or sync data manually:
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer